# How to refresh a Dojo ItemFileReadStore in a FilteringSelect box

Tags: select, dojo, refresh, store

I want to be able to force a refresh of this Dojo ItemFileReadStore.  Any ideas how I do that?

```
            existingCasesStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ url: "some url here" });
            existingCasesStore.fetch();

            // Creates the Choose Existing list box
            new dojo.form.FilteringSelect({
                store: existingCasesStore,
                autocomplete: true,
                maxHeight: "300",
                required: false,
                id: "choose_existing_select_id",
                onChange: function(selected) {
                    utils.setStatusMessage("case_info_status", "", "&nbsp;");
                }
            }, "choose_existing_select_id");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try implement the following

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html#reloading-refreshing-itemfilereadstore-from-a-data-object-dojo-toolkit-1-4

Basically, close the store so that it will call a new `fetch` next time items are read

Answer (score 2):

mschr,

Thanks for the tip.. here's what I did to make it work.

```
existingCasesStore.close();
existingCasesStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data: testData });
existingCasesStore.fetch();
dijit.byId('choose_existing_select_id').set("store", existingCasesStore);
```

Comment: i dont think you need to instantiate a new store instance, however its a little different how the widgets attached to them (in this case filteringselect) re-renders their contents. set("store",..) definately will call the correct rendering functions after - so thumbs up =)